# stringWithFormat Issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, stringwithformat

I am having a small issue in my application. I have it to where when the user presses the facebook button the `SLComposeViewController` pops up with text in it that I have preset. That is where my problem comes in. I would like it to say **I just climbed** and then at the end, whatever climb that they pressed into. Example: **I just climbed Mount Everest**. The **I just climbed** part I can get to show up, but when I try and use `stringWithFormat` it gives me an error which I will post below, along with my code. The climb title is set a a label in my DVC with this line `self.titleLabel.text = self.climbTitle;`

**Line with problem:**

```
[mySLComposerSheet setInitialText:NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@Climbed", [_climbTitle];
```

**Error:**

```
DetailViewController.m:79:39: Unexpected interface name 'NSString': expected expression
```

I hope I have worded this question appropriately and have given enough context for everyone to understand my issue, if I haven't, please inform me and I will correct it.

Thanks

Comment: This is not an Xcode question. This is a question about your code and/or the usage of the NSString class and/or Objective-C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@Climbed", _climbTitle];`

Comment: NO you cant. You should have the object of `DetailViewController.h` in the other class. and declare `climbTitle` as property. Then you can access like `detailViewObject.climbTitle`